# Youtube Blob urls don't work in browsers but in src

Tags: javascript, url, blob, fileapi, media-source

I know that there are no blob urls only objects.
I made my own blob object for a video buffer and then I used it in a src of video tag which is something like *blob://website.com/blablobbla* . I opened this url in the browser it worked

> when I opened the url of youtube video src (blob url) into a new tab it did't work but mine video src (blob url) worked

I want to know how can I do the same with my blob urls so that they only work in the src of the html video tag and give error or don't work in the external tab/window of the browsers.I just want to know the technology behind this and blob objects and their url properties.

Comment: Ans needed on this question same problem I am facing. tried to search a lot but still empty hands. :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question seems somewhat vague to me, so here is what I interpret (also from the code in the fiddle-images in your question):

- you receive a `Blob` (image's binary data) through a `XMLHttpRequest()` `GET`-request (`responseType = 'blob'`)
- you create a `Blob URL` with `URL.createObjectURL()` in the `URL Store` for `XMLHttpRequest()` `response`-object (the `Blob` holding the binary data)
- you set the resulting `Blob URL`-string as `src` for a image (and append the image to the document, thereby showing the image you just downloaded)
- You "don't want it to work in new tab" ("it" being the `Blob URL`-string I assume).

In your comments you say:

- > In fiddle I *inspected the image and copied the src and then pasted it in new tab* and it worked and showed the image *I don't want the image to be shown directly with the blob url.*
- > If you go to youtube and open the src of video in new tab : It will not work,, *I want this to happen*

It appears to me that you do *not* want the user to be able to view/download the blob when they copy the `Blob URL`-string (by examining the live source or simply `right-click-on-image>>Copy Imagelocation`) and paste it into a new tab/window (for which you give youtube as an example).

But you are *also* talking about video's.

**TL;DR:** It seems your question/bounty might be mixing up 2 different types of URL returned by `window.URL.createObjectURL();`:

- [`Blob URL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#url) referencing (objects that represent) 'raw local data' (like (Local-)File, Blob, etc.)
  For these you want to automatically (or programmatically) **revoke** the `Blob URL` from the browser's `URL Store` (which you could consider a simplified local webserver inside the browser, only available to that browser).

  - [`var myBlobURL=window.URL.createObjectURL(object, flag_oneTimeOnly);`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-createObjectURL) 
    returns a re-usable `Blob URL` which **can be revoked with:** [`window.URL.revokeObjectURL(myBlobURL)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-revokeObjectURL) (adds the `Blob URL` string to the `Revocation List`).
    <sub>Note: there used to be a second argument `flag_oneTimeOnly` which used to revoke the `Blob URL` automatically after it's first use, but that is currently no longer part of the spec! Also this flag often didn't work anyway (at least in firefox).</sub>
  - [`var myBlobURL=window.URL.createFor(object);`](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-createFor)
    returns a `Blob URL` that is **automatically revoked after it's first use**.
    <sub>Note: quite some browsers were 'late' to implement this one.</sub>
- [`MediaSource object URL`](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#mediasource-object-url) referencing a *special* [MediaSource Object](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#mediasource)
  These URL's are

  - only intended to link `src` of a [`HTMLMediaElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement) (think `<audo>` & `<video>` elements) to the special `MediaSource Object`
    <sub>Note: a new tab/window is not an `HTMLMediaElement`</sub>
  - [*already* **automatically revoked**](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#url)
    <sub>Note: even though they are created through `window.URL.createObjectURL();`</sub>

---

**Here's what's happening for the fiddle in your question's image *and similar code that downloaded a video as `Blob` (where you downloaded the whole video-file's data/binary on the server using an xhr)* or any other 'local' data:**
You are essentially using the 'bare' 'un-enhanced' [File-API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).
The `URL Store` is only maintained during a session (so it will survive a page-refresh, since it is still the same session) and lost when the document is unloaded.
So, if your fiddle is still open, then fiddle-document (the document that created the `Blob URL`) is obviously *not* yet unloaded, and therefore it's `Blob URL`s are available to the browser (any tab/window) as long as it is not revoked!
This is a relevant *feature*: you can build/download/modify a `Blob` in the browser, create a `Blob URL` and set it as `href` to a file-download link (which the user can right-click and open in a new tab/window!!)
Close the fiddle or revoke the `Blob URL` from the `URL Store` and the `Blob URL` is no longer accessible (also not in a different tab/window).

**Try yourself with your modified fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/7cyoozwv/
In this fiddle it should now no longer be possible to load your sample image into a different tab/window after you copied the image url (once the image is displayed in your page).
Here I revoked the URL manually (`revokeObjectURL()`) as it is currently the best cross-browser method (partially due to the api not yet fully being stabilized).
Also note: an element's `onload` event can be an elegant place to revoke your `Blob URL`.

---

**Here is what's happening to an `<audio>` or `<video>` source linked to an `MediaSource Object` using an `MediaSource object URL` returned by `window.URL.createObjectURL(MediaSource)`:**
The [Media Source Extensions (MSE)](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/)  *also extend* the `File-API`'s `window.URL.createObjectURL()` to accept a `MediaSource Object`. The (current draft of the) [URL Object Extension](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/#url) specifies that:

> This algorithm is intended to mirror the behavior of the createObjectURL()[FILE-API] method with autoRevoke set to true.

<sup>Note that the current spec of the `File API`'s `window.URL.createObjectURL()` *no longer* has an `autoRevoke` (or `flag_oneTimeOnly`) boolean flag accessible to the programmer who should be using `window.URL.createFor()` for this purpose instead. I wonder when the Media-Source spec will mimic that (and for backward compatibility alias their `createObjectURL()` to a new `createFor()` extension (seems more appropriate as that is how it seems to be intended to work currently)).</sup>

These resulting **automatically revoked URL-strings** are *only intended* to link the `src` of a `HTMLMediaElement` (think `<audo>` & `<video>` elements) to the special `MediaSource Object`.
<sub>I don't think that an empty `Document` (from a new tab/window) is a `<audo>` or `<video>` element.</sub>

Perhaps "A quick tutorial on MSE"<sup>(source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))</sup> might help clarify the difference and basic use:

> To use the MSE API, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Define an HTML5 `video` element in the HTML section of a page.
> 2. Create a `MediaSource` object in JavaScript.
> 3. Create a virtual URL using `createObjectURL` with the `MediaSource` object as the source.
> 4. Assign the virtual URL to the video element's `src` property.
> 5. Create a `SourceBuffer` using `addSourceBuffer`, with the mime type of the video you're adding.
> 6. Get the video initialization segment from the media file online and add it to the `SourceBuffer` with `appendBuffer`.
> 7. Get the segments of video data from the media file, append them to the `SourceBuffer` with `appendBuffer`.
> 8. Call the `play` method on the video element.
> 9. Repeat step 7 until done.
> 10. Clean up.

---

You (or a big-time player like youtube who will dynamically select supported technologies for playback on the client's platform (so there is no way to tell for sure what kind of youtube video URL's you are talking about)) *could* be using the new special `MediaSource Object` to play video's (or audio).
This adds buffer-based source options to HTML5 video for streaming support (compared to to downloading a complete video file before playing or use an add-on like Silverlight or Adobe Flash to stream media).

Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: I got everything now.
ThanksAlso.

Comment: OMG your answer was very long to read.Just keep it simple to understand.

Comment: Thank you (for accept and bounty), and you are welcome! For what it's worth, I think a bounty-answer should provide all relevant reference and source; without explanation the answer would literally just be: "revocation and Document !== HTMLMediaElement". I also felt it was important to point out how the counter-intuitive createObjectURL() does completely different things depending on how you use it (I'm always having a battle to combine short and complete). I just re-checked my fiddle, was working ok. I assume you got it to work in the end?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the URL that you're referring is just a `"string"` reference to the `BLOB` itself (which is created using the function `window.URL.createObjectURL`); So, that you can use it like a normal URL. And, the scope is also only until the document is unloaded.

So, I don't think it is possible for you to open the URL just using browser. And also I tried to re-create what you're saying but with no avail (in my own website, create a blob and put the URL into browser).

Below is the code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://kurrik.github.io/hackathons/static/img/sample-128.png");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function response(e) {
   var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
   console.log(imageUrl);
   var imgDOM = document.createElement("img");

   imgDOM.src = imageUrl;
   document.getElementById("divImage").appendChild(imgDOM);
};
xhr.send();
```

The fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qnmgx5pc/)

---

Update :

Ok, after I looked at it. seems like youtube is using [media-source](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source/) to stream the video.

I haven't updated the fiddle (cannot found a video that I can use). But, basically, It still using the same function (`createObjectURL`) to create the blob URL. But, instead of using the source (image, video, etc) to pass to the function. You should pass the `MediaSource` object into the function.

And then, you use the blob URL and pass it into the `video.src`. Therefore, when you try to open the blob link. You should not be able to see the video again.

Comment: that exactly what happened in the code above. try open the value in `imageUrl` in another tab and you will see ;) (though obviously not using htaccess to do that)

Comment: In fiddle I inspected the image and copied the src and then pasted it in new tab and it worked and showed the image I don't want the image to be shown directly with the blob url.

Comment: Well, can you pass me the URL that you use? because when I try it, it will always be a 404 page.

Comment: If I pass the url to you it'll not work in your browser because the url is created using random numbers by the browser.

Comment: First, more like UUID than random numbers. Second, I'm starting to guessing how exactly you tried to open the image?. Seems like you're confused between the URL that the BLOB is referring to with the real URL that really directing to the file. So, you might need to put a step by step on how exactly you do this (if possible with screenshot to clarify things) on the question.